# How to solve a linear equation by substitution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been having a tough time figuring this out. This is how I wrote out the question with substitution.

$$\begin{align}
& I_2 = I_1 + aI_1 (T_2 - T_1) \\
& I_1=100\\
&T_2=35\\
&T_1=-5\\
&a=0.000011
\end{align}$$

My try was $I_2 = 100(1) + 0.000011(100) (35(2)-5(1))$

The answer is $100.044$m but I can't figure out the mechanics of the question.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I tried to post a screen shot of the question, but I don't have enough points to do so. If you click on question though it will show the image.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For the best results, try to give as much information as you think is pertinent. In this case, give your values, for instance, is $I_1=100$ correct? If you are not certain exactly how to format, do the best you can to make it (at least) human interpretable, and someone *will* translate it for you into LaTeX, in order that the information is best communicated to this vast and knowledgeable site!

Comment: @CaviB I have updated the post with LaTeX, can you please confirm that this is correct?

Comment: @gekkostate:  I think I got it right.  CaviB please confirm.

Comment: Yes it's correct thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The lower temperature is $-5$ and you dropped a sign plus should not be multiplying $T_2$ by $2$.  The correct calculation is $I_2=100+0.000011\cdot 100 \cdot (35-(-5))=100.044$

Comment: Yeah I totally misunderstood the substitution (l1 = 100 not 100(1) and T2 = 35 not 35(2)). Thanks again for the guys.